# setInterval won't change image on Safari, but on Chrome

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a mock array that distributes data. One component uses this data to display a list of cases. Each case has allocated images. When one case is being hovered, only then these images are being displayed, but only one at a time - every interval of 300ms the images changes.

**My code works, but I have trouble with Safari - the image won't change.** Somehow Safari can't handle it. Increasing the interval from 300m to 3000ms made it work, but that's not the way I want it to work.

Looking at the code in safari proves that the image actually switches every 300ms, since the img source changes - but the change won't be displayed.

*BTW I tried it with Chrome and it worked fine.*

```
export class CaseListComponent implements OnInit {

  counter = 1;
  cases;
  interval;

  image: string;
  array = [];

  mouseEnter(url: string, url2: string, url3: string, name: string) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.array = [url, url2, url3];
    this.image = this.array[0];
    this.changeImage();
  }

  changeImage() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.image = this.array[this.counter];
    this.counter = this.counter === 2 ? 0 : this.counter + 1;
  }, 300);
}

  mouseLeave() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.image = null;
    this.highlightedItem = null;
  }

  constructor(private casesService: CasesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cases = this.casesService.data;
  }



}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center" *ngFor="let case of cases" [class.z-index]="highlightedItem === case.name">
      <p class="d-inline-block" routerLink="/cases/{{ case.id }}" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter(case.image, case.image2, case.image3, case.name)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()"
         [style.color]="highlightedItem !== case.name && highlightedItem !== null ? '#f1f1f1' : '#33393D'">{{ case.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img *ngIf="!!image" [src]="image" alt="image" class="position-fixed align-self-center">

</div>
```

Comment: Try using observables instead ? Angular heavily relies on them, and if you do so, you can also the `onPush` change detection strategy to increas your component performance.

Comment: @Maryannah Could you please illustrate your answer? Since I'm new to Angular I haven't really worked a lot with observables yet.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, you should use observables.

They are heavily used in Angular and you can rely on it for your change detection.

Here is a simple example of the observables in action, without Angular. Simply adapt this to your code (and ask if you have any issue) to make Angular handle the picture changes.

[**Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-liskov-dzkd6)

```js
import { fromEvent, Subscription, timer } from "rxjs";
import {} from "rxjs/operators";

const container = document.querySelector(".container");

let subscription: Subscription;

let count = 0;

const cycler = timer(0, 500);

fromEvent(container, "mouseenter").subscribe(() => {
  subscription = cycler.subscribe(() => {
    count++;
    container.textContent = count;
  });
});

fromEvent(container, "mouseleave").subscribe(() => {
  subscription && subscription.unsubscribe();
  container.textContent = "";
  count = 0;
});
```

Comment: I cant get it running - somehow the target is always invalid even though i added the class to html and how do I get access to the data I passed by hovering?